# Можно ли создать несколько датасорсов для spring-repository?

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, repository

Spring-приложение, использующее jpa-repository, oracle и развернутое на was8.5.5.13

Возникла задача по записи в базу большого объема данных(11млн сущностей)
Изначально в проекте создан singleton dataSource, который используется jpa-репозиторием для записи в базу.

На данный момент эта операция занимает очень времени(примерно 10 часов), поэтому возникла необходимость в многопоточность.
Создал потоки, увеличил connection-pool для датасорса на сервере, но, это не решает проблему.
20 потоков отрабатывают за то же время, что и один.

Я подозреваю, что проблема кроется в в операциях записи в базу, что используется только один датасорс(закрываются и открываются потоки)

Как это можно побороть, можно ли как-то сообщить dataSource или EntityManager'у что я хочу быстрее, что можно создавать много коннекшенов?

датасорс выглядит так

```
    @Bean
    @Resource(type = DataSource.class, lookup = "jdbc/MyProject", name = "jdbc/MyProject")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyProject");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Entity-manager

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES);
    entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    log.info("Entity Manager configured.");
    return entityManager;
}
```

Обновление:
Судя по мониторингу на самом сервере, кол-во соединений не зависит в текущий момент от того сколько я создал потоков.
Потоков 20, соединений 1-2  (pool-connection)

Comment: когда говорят о записи кучи данных в БД, я вспоминаю слова Bulk Insert. Я не знаю, есть оно в оракле и что это значит уже не помню, но [поищите](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall), возможно это [то, что вам нужно](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update).

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/50772230/312041